# QGIS 2.8 Composer - extent overview not shown

Tags: printing, print-composer, qgis-2.8

I have a print composition with three maps:

1. a general map (1),
2. a medium-scale map (2)
3. and my detailed map (0).

I want a box showing the extend of map0, in map2.

For doing that I block the layer in map0 and then go to map2 and create a new Overview. Then I select map0 as Map Frame, but nothing happens; no extent frame is shown.

I've tried redrawing the map, also tried with different blending modes. I did it a couple of months ago, with QGIS2.6.

Could it be a bug of the new version?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by blocking the layers of map0? Your right on creating the overview on map2. Did you try it with just a single layer? See picture below of a working sample with setting. The large map is map0 the small inserted map with the overview is map1.

[image]

Comment: I have to lock map0 to avoid map0 changing when I am doing my map1 (overview) because I have different layers in map0 and map1.  
I tried on QGIS 2.10.1 and the issue remains. The configuration of both maps is exactly the same you show in your picture.  
I also tried with a new project and one layer for the detailed map and one for the overview and got no inset frame.  
Finally, I tried using a single layer and I get still no inset frame.  
I would like to show you the images but I don't know how to write the reference to a local image file.  
Thanks for your interest!!  
Asier

Comment: I have a similar issue where I can only add an overview to the map itself (map 1 will get highlighed in a red box ON MAP1) and I can't select any regions in map 0)